# TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, flask

I am working on this tutorial.[flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)

However, I got the above error when I work with web forms.

Here is the error message generated by Flask.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\workspace\Learn-flask\app\views.py", line 17, in login
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In',form=form)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\templating.py", line 128, in render_template
context, ctx.app)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask-0.10-py2.7.egg\flask\templating.py", line 110, in _render
rv = template.render(context)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in render
return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.1-py2.7.egg\jinja2\environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\workspace\Learn-flask\app\templates\login.html", line 1, in top-level template code
{% extends "base.html"%}
File "C:\workspace\Learn-flask\app\templates\base.html", line 17, in top-level template code
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
File "C:\workspace\Learn-flask\app\templates\login.html", line 9, in block "content"
<p>Open id :{{form.openid(80)}}<br/>
```

Here is the form class code

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

Where I have done the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wtforms.fields.Field.__call__`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__) only takes keyword arguments, as the [linked documentation](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__) states.  If you want to pass `80` as [`maxlen`](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.StringField) then use the keyword argument:

```
{{ form.openid(maxlength=80) }}
```

Comment: The way you have find the solution is very smart. I didn't search on WTForms. Thanks.